# Can you put color only on certain words/paragraphs/lines?

Tags: c++, colors, calendar

i have a calendar in c++ and i wanted to put certain colors on certain days for each different month, but i dont know how, so i tried to at least put a certain color for every month, but i cant manage to do it. I used this code at the end of the main code, but i tried putting it anywhere tbh:
system("color A");
std::cout<<"hi"<<std::endl;

This is the entire code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int dayNumber(int day, int month, int year)
{
static int t[] = { 0,3,2,5,0,3,5,1,4,6,2,4 };
year -= month < 3;
return (year + year / 4 - year / 100 + year / 400 + t[month - 1] + day) % 7;
}

string getMonthName(int monthNumber)
// returns the names of the months in the order i wrote them to be
{
string months[] = { "January", "February", "March", "April",
                    "May", "June", "July", "August",
                    "September", "October", "November", "December" };
return (months[monthNumber]);
}

 int numberOfDays(int monthNumber, int year)
 // returns the number of days each month has, and instead of having numbers from 28 to 31 i 
 put 30 for each month there is
{
// January
if (monthNumber == 0)
    return (30);
// February
if (monthNumber == 1)
    return (30);
// March
if (monthNumber == 2)
    return (30);
// April
if (monthNumber == 3)
    return (30);
// May
if (monthNumber == 4)
    return (30);
// June
if (monthNumber == 5)
    return (30);
// July
if (monthNumber == 6)
    return (30);
// August
if (monthNumber == 7)
    return (30);
// September
if (monthNumber == 8)
    return (30);
// October
if (monthNumber == 9)
    return (30);
// November
if (monthNumber == 10)
    return (30);
// December
if (monthNumber == 11)
    return (30);
 }

  void printCalendar(int year)
  // making a calendar for the months and days to be in order and nice looking
  {
 printf(" Calendar - %d\n\n", year);
 int days;
 int current = dayNumber (1, 1, year);
 // i is for iterating months
 // j is for iterating days of the months
 for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
 {
    days = numberOfDays(i, year);
    //The name of the current month
    printf("\n -------------%s------------- \n",
        getMonthName(i).c_str());
    //The columns for each day in the week so they dont get mixed together
    printf(" Sun  Mon  Tue  Wed  Thu  Fri  Sat\n");

    /* blank spaces for the spaces in the calendar that dont regard the days in the exact 
   month, for example if 30 was on monday,
    we would see the next 6 days as blank, as they are not part of this month, but are part of 
  the other month */
    int k;
    for (k = 0; k < current; k++)
        printf("     ");

    for (int j = 1; j <= days; j++)
    {
        printf("%5d", j);
        if (++k > 6)
        {
            k = 0;
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    if (k)
        printf("\n");

    current = k;
   }
   return;
   }
   // here we put what year we want, but it doesnt matter as the months have all 30 days, 
   //therefor whatever year we put we still have the same amounts of days

   void Color(int color)
     {
   SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), color);
   }

   int main()
  {

    system("color A");
    std::cout<<"hi"<<std::endl;

    int year = 2020;
    printCalendar(year);
    return 0;
   }
```

Comment: if you set the color once at the beginning of `main` and never reset it then it will stay like that. You can change the color before printing colored text and change it back to non-colored after printing colored text

Comment: Colored console output depends on the console.  There exists (existed?) terminals that only support colors for whole physical lines (think rasters).  There are other terminals that can support color for individual characters (actually cells on the screen).  Now let's talk about GUI console windows, which may be able to support colored graphics, in which you can draw your own characters using separate colored pixels.

Comment: Your `getMonthName` function takes an `int` parameter.  The `int` type can be negative.  Pass it a -20 and see what happens.  Another test case is our favorite numbers, 0 and 13.

Comment: Since you have array for month names, you can also have an array of days per month.  This would remove a lot of code from your program.

Comment: Your `numberOfDays` function doesn't use the `year` parameter.  Usually the `year` parameter is used to handle the leap year calculation.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use **system** command, it will change the color of your whole console and will not be specific for a certain text on console.

Instead, use the SetTextConsoleAttribute function, as you did in your Color function. You may simply call the Color function wherever you want the color of console to change.

For example,

```
int main()
{
Color(7); // Use this color as default 
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
if (i == 4)
Color(10); // Change color to 10 if i = 4, otherwise use the default color. 

cout << i << " "; 
Color(7); // Change color to default. 

}
}
```

I have modified your code to change the color for the complete month of Feburary and also for some specific days of November. Use the same pattern in any way you wish to color your Calendar. I have also added comments with all the changes I have made for better understanding. Ask any confusion if you still have any.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void Color(int); // Make prototype of function. 
int dayNumber(int day, int month, int year)
{
    static int t[] = { 0,3,2,5,0,3,5,1,4,6,2,4 };
    year -= month < 3;
    return (year + year / 4 - year / 100 + year / 400 + t[month - 1] + day) % 7;
}

string getMonthName(int monthNumber)
// returns the names of the months in the order i wrote them to be
{
    string months[] = { "January", "February", "March", "April",
                        "May", "June", "July", "August",
                        "September", "October", "November", "December" };
    return (months[monthNumber]);
}

int numberOfDays(int monthNumber, int year)
// returns the number of days each month has, and instead of having numbers from 28 to 31 i 
{
    // January
    if (monthNumber == 0)
        return (30);
// February
if (monthNumber == 1)
    return (30);
// March
if (monthNumber == 2)
    return (30);
// April
if (monthNumber == 3)
    return (30);
// May
if (monthNumber == 4)
    return (30);
// June
if (monthNumber == 5)
    return (30);
// July
if (monthNumber == 6)
    return (30);
// August
if (monthNumber == 7)
    return (30);
// September
if (monthNumber == 8)
    return (30);
// October
if (monthNumber == 9)
    return (30);
// November
if (monthNumber == 10)
    return (30);
// December
if (monthNumber == 11)
    return (30);
}

void printCalendar(int year)
// making a calendar for the months and days to be in order and nice looking
{
    printf(" Calendar - %d\n\n", year);
    int days;
    int current = dayNumber(1, 1, year);
    // i is for iterating months
    // j is for iterating days of the months
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        if (i == 1) // If month is Feb
            Color(10); 
        days = numberOfDays(i, year);
        //The name of the current month
        printf("\n -------------%s------------- \n",
            getMonthName(i).c_str());
        //The columns for each day in the week so they dont get mixed together
        printf(" Sun  Mon  Tue  Wed  Thu  Fri  Sat\n");

        /* blank spaces for the spaces in the calendar that dont regard the days in the exact
       month, for example if 30 was on monday,
        we would see the next 6 days as blank, as they are not part of this month, but are part of
      the other month */
        int k;
        for (k = 0; k < current; k++)
            printf("     ");

        for (int j = 1; j <= days; j++)
        {
            if (i == 10) // If the month is November 
            {
                switch (j)
                {
                case 5:
                case 6:
                case 15:
                    Color(12); // For the days of 5, 6, 7 => Change color to Red. 
                    break;
                default:
                    Color(7); // Otherwise, use the default color. 
                }
            }
            printf("%5d", j);
            if (++k > 6)
            {
                k = 0;
                printf("\n");
            }
        }
        if (k)
            printf("\n");

        current = k;
        Color(7); // Change color to default color 
    }
    return;
}
// here we put what year we want, but it doesnt matter as the months have all 30 days, 
//therefor whatever year we put we still have the same amounts of days

void Color(int color)
{
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), color);
}

int main()
{
    Color(7); // Default Color. Use color value = 7 
    std::cout << "hi" << std::endl;

    int year = 2020;
    printCalendar(year);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it really, really helps. I have tried some other things aswell, but they kept giving me errors and i didnt know how to fix them. Thank you so much.